# restore a sqlserver 2005 database into sqlserver 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a db running on an instance of sqlserver 2003, Ive tried to import it into sqlserver 2012 but that wont work it's says it's to old.

so I've imported it into sqlserver 2005, I have then backed it up again and tried to import it into sqlserver 2012 but it comes up with the same error.

I can restore other db's from sqlserver 2005 so I can only presume its keeping its 2003 settings when I back it up.

Can anyone help

Comment: i don't think you really have sql server 2003 because it never existed ... there was sql server 2000 and then 2005 ... anyway ... maybe it helps if you change the compatibility level of your database after you restored it to sql server 2005

Comment: Exactly what error are you getting?

Comment: Keep in mind that the suggestion to change compatibility levels of your database might end up breaking functionality. If, for instance, you have views, functions or stored procedures using functionality that was deprecated in 2005, those objects would no longer work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your database might have some deprecated functionality that prevents your upgrade from working.

There's a list of deprecated functionality between SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 on [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179(v=sql.90).aspx).

I would strongly advise you to use the [SQL Server 2005 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1470E86B-7E05-4322-A677-95AB44F12D75) to identify such functionality, and address any potential issues. Then, and only then you should have a database compatible with SQL Server 2005, and can (hopefully) proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

if u want database structure only then take database script then run into sql server 2005, if u want database with data also mean

1. right click the Database go task
2. click Generate Script
3. There Two options entire database or with specific objects
4. entire database for DataBase structure only
5. with specific objects - select all objects then click Next you find the Advance button then click it.
6. scroll down and Find Type of Data Scripts click and change to Schema and data then you will save as file file or new query window

this is one of the method to restore the database.

Answer (score 0):

Set your compatibility level to (90) Sql server 2005 in your database properties after restoring.